# Razor to favor simpler methodology

Tags: occams-razor

### problem :

Two methodologies can be used to solve the same problem. One methodology is simple while the second is complex.

### question :

Is there a razor to support methodology one? Or is there a razor to support methodology two?

### current belief :

I believe occam's razor applies to dealing with assumptions, and therefore doesn't apply.

Thank you!

Comment: if both solutions achieve exactly the same outcome, why choose the more complex solution?

Comment: These sorts of things are called parsimony principles, the Occam's Razor (ontological parsimony) is one of them. But you can add any adjective you like, in this case methodological parsimony, see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/simplicity/), and "Occam's Razor" is often loosely/indiscriminately applied to all of them.